# File name too long error when running a linux command with a long argument

Tags: linux, paste, cut

I'm trying to `cut` a single column from 100 files and `paste` them together using this linux command:

```
paste <(cut -f 5 file_1.tsv) <(cut -f 5 file_2.tsv) <(cut -f 5 file_3.tsv) ... <(cut -f 5 file_100.tsv) > combined.tsv
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
File name too long
```

Any recommendations how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably get this message because command line size is limited. I advise you try to do it with a loop. Here is an example of what you could do --- beware, because the order might not be what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" >  combined.tsv

#build your file list
find . -name "file*tsv" |sort -k1 > list_files.lst

#the process the list
while read x ; do
  x=`basename ${x}`
  paste <(cat combined.tsv) <(cut -f 5 ${x} ) > combined${x}.tsv
  mv combined${x}.tsv combined.tsv
done< list_files.lst

#you do not need it anymore
rm list_files.lst
```

(this is to be put in a file, e.g. `myscript.sh`, then `chmod +x  myscript.sh`, then run it like below

```
./myscript.sh
```

)